# use python to raise an exception if a user-defined class is passed an array of the incorrect shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a class that gets passed an array. I want to raise an exception unless that array is the correct length. I would prefer to accomplish this using the "try...except" feature of python, and have the program exit if an array of the incorrect length is passed. How can this behavior be accomplished?

This seems like something "isinstance" was designed for, but I do not know how to require that the passed array be an ndarray of a specific shape.

Comment: try ... except is used to catch an exception, not to raise one.

Comment: "_How can this behavior be accomplished?_" You can't, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 7):

```
def func(arr):
    if not isinstance(arr, np.ndarray) or arr.shape != (1, 5):
         raise ValueError("Passed array is not of the right shape")
    ...
```

Comment: The typical way this is used practically is, rather than checking the type, trying to convert it to an array, so that other sequence objects like lists are also valid inputs. If it cannot be converted, numpy will raise an informative exception. So the code would typically look like: `arr = np.asarray(arr); if arr.shape != ...`